# php speed up large foreach

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a SQL Query that returns a large dataset in less than a second. What I need to do is fix my PHP Laravel code which is taking serveral seconds to parse and display the data. It displays it all in one table and then I use DataTables to paginate it because I need to be able to search through all of it.

This is my Laravel Blade code:

```
<div class="body">


 @if(Request::url() === 'http://clashdata.tk/clans')
    <h2>2000 Oldest Active Clans</h2>
 @elseif(Request::url() === 'http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/level')
    <h2>2000 Clans In Order of Level</h2>
 @elseif(Request::url() === 'http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/score')
    <h2>2000 Clans In Order of Score</h2>
 @elseif(Request::url() === 'http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/warclans')
    <h2>2000 Best War Clans</h2>
 @elseif(Request::url() === 'http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/warswon')
    <h2>2000 Clans In Order of Wars Won</h2>
 @endif

<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Order By...</option>
    <option value="http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/score">Clan Points</option>
    <option value="http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/level">Clan Level and Exp</option>
    <option value="http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/warclans">Best War Clans</option>
    <option value="http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/warswon">Wars Won</option>
    <option value="http://clashdata.tk/clans/">Time Made</option>
</select>


<br /><br />

<table cellspacing="20" id="table" border="1" class="display dataTable dtr-inline" style="border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Search Clan Names</td>
            <td>Players</td>
            <td>Wars Won</td>
            <td>Wars Lost</td>
            <td>Wars Tied</td>
            <td>Clan Level</td>
            <td>Clan Experience</td>
            <td>Search Clan Locations</td>
            @if(Request::url() === 'http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/warclans')
                <td>War Rating</td>
            @else
                <td>War Win %</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    @foreach($clan as $currentclan)

    <tr>

        <td>{{ $currentclan->rank }}</td>
        <td><a href="/clans/{{ $currentclan->id }}">{{ $currentclan->name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->playercount }}</td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->warswon }}</td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->warslost }}</td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->warstied }}</td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->level }}</td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->exp }}</td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->location }}</td>
        <td>{{ $currentclan->warwinpercent }}</td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach
    </tbody>

</table>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready( function () {

        $('#table').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ],
            "autoWidth": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        });

        $('#table').dataTable().columnFilter({
            sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
            aoColumns: [null, { type: "text" }, null, null, null, null, null, null, { type: "text" }, null]
        });

    } );
</script>
```

What should I do to speed this up?

The SQL Query is 2.4M so I made a script here which contains the following code:

```
<?php

print str_repeat("a",24000000);
```

http://clashdata.tk/so.php

Does that help debugging it?

Comment: You should use server-side processing

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar how???

Comment: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: that doesnt solve the foreach problem..

Comment: There is no foreach problem;  you should only be returning part of your data. Then send ajax requests when you need to search through the rest.  That way you never have to @foreach through more than a screens-worth of rows.

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar can't get much help from that link though.. Right now if I try and fetch all rows it doesn't even work.. I get a blank screen shown instead...

Answer (score 1):

Echoing out all rows of your data is a poor design when you have a lot of data to display.  It is better to echo out only chunks of your data.  Datatables provides a useful way to do this:

https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Step 1:  Set up html and javascript

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<script>
//assuming you have included all prerequisite scripts for Datatables
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "url_to_your_server_processing_script.php"
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Step 2: write php script that will return just a chunk of your data like this:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [[
      "Airi",
      "Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "28th Nov 08",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica",
      "Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "9th Oct 09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ]]
}
```

Datatables also gives examples on how to filter your data by passing search parameters to your php script so you can choose what to return. If you search google for `datatables server-side processing example` , you will find more complete examples.

Laravel/Eloquent simple example (not complete)

```
Use App\Clan

$count = Clan::count();
$clans = Clan::where('some_column','some_value')
    ->skip(20)
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

return [
    'draw' => 1,
    'recordsTotal' => $count,
    'recordsFiltered' => 10,
    'data' => $clans,
]
```

Comment: Almost there: you need to reduce the number of rows returned and place it inside the value of the `"data"` parameter in the json object above.  You also need to return values for the other parameters: `"draw","recordsTotal","recordsFiltered"`

Comment: wait what? I don't understand that bit. Also what if I need one of the columns to be a link which will be dependant on another element inside the json object?

Comment: I edited my response to include a quick example of grabbing Eloquent Model data for Datatables (not tested).

Comment: What if I want to fetch 10,000 the results from the dB but want it paginated to display 100 on each? Right now: http://clashdata.tk/clans

Comment: If I turn serverSide to false then it is all working. It is still fetching from ajax but even with serverside true http://clashdata.tk/clans/orderby/warswon/load which is fetching all 157K result isn't completing, let alone in a good time... Using the command line I had it output all rows in 27 seconds..

Comment: You need to choose which 100 records to return on each request to your script.  Do not return all the records.

Comment: @Douglas.Seasar what about when I want to search through the full table?

Comment: The searching takes place on the server where you are choosing which 100 records to send back to the browser.

Comment: Pagination? How would that work then? Can you by any chance update your answer with all the full details and example code? Surely this would mean I have to change the eloquent code but how do I change it for pagination...?

Comment: You will need the `start` and `length` parameters for pagination.  You should really look at the documentation: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side .